# Dynamic margin on content after close cookiebar

Tags: html, css, cookies

I have a simple page divided into sections:

- Cookie bar (Position fixed all the time on top).
- Header (Position fixed all the time on top below cookie bar).
- navigation bar (Position fixed all the time on top below cookie bar and header (logo etc)).
- content (below all of them).

3 elements are fixed but one of them can be closed (cookie bar). How to set dynamic margin-top for content div, when the cookie bar is closed the bar content moves up?

Simple Example:

```
<body>
 <div id=cookieBar>
  Cookie Content... If you agree, please close:                   x
 </div>
 <div id=container>
  <div id=header>
    header
  </div>
  <div id=nav>
    Nav
  </div>
</div>

<div id=content>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec sed porta mi. Ut lobortis nisl eget varius mattis. 
Proin vehicula mauris a lorem pharetra, cursus consequat orci pulvinar. Vivamus finibus lacinia sapien nec iaculis. 
Mauris condimentum convallis mi ut suscipit. 
Suspendisse justo purus, pretium vel euismod vitae, scelerisque vel dui. Etiam ut euismod nulla.
</div>
```

And style:

```
<style>
  #header{
    background-color: red;
  }
  #nav{
      background-color: blue;
  }

  #container{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #content{
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

I would like to remove constant margin-top: 100px and set something dynamic.

Comment: How do you close the cookie bar? Where is the code?

Comment: Just   display: none. I didn't put the code because am writing in GWT (Java framework) so the code looks a little bit different than raw CSS and HTML.